# How can I condense multiple lookups from one Object, to one related list?

Tags: custom-object, related-list, product, lookup-field

Use Case:

I have a custom object that I've created, that can look up to the Salesforce standard object Product, up to 12 times. Because of the field structure of doing that, it has created 12 separate Related Lists.

Is there any way I can condense all these related lists into 1? A pivot related list, so to speak...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a join object?  Your data model has multiple issues (as you are seeing) and is not scalable.

Comment: How would you use a join object in this case?

Comment: @DavidCheng, also, what are the other issues? I want to get better at this! 

This issue I have posted isn't even an "issue" yet. I just want to get ahead of it

Comment: See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&type=5 and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrFA4yli8Jc

Comment: I think based on that video, this would be considered a junction object. I would still like to talk more about other issues I am having, and if you have an idea of how to perhaps shore up this idea, if you have some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can query them all and display them on the custom component using the lightning data table.

[Aura Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) | [Lwc Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example)